# Using r in Google Colab to read file and values appear as NAs

Tags: r, file, google-colaboratory

I have a large txt tab delimited file (around 24000 rows and 71 columns) and I am trying to read the file using the following code

```
kirc <- read.delim(file=kirc_path,header = TRUE, sep = "\t",check.names = FALSE)
```

I used the same code in RStudio with no issues, but with Google Colab many values appear as NAs with no obvious reasons!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that it read entire rows as NAs and the index of these columns was outside the dimension of my dataframe

```
dim(kirc)
```

For some reason, reading the file created so many rows with empty values which created the NAs issue.
So subsetting the dataframe to the actual dimension solved the issue.

```
kirc = kirc[1:dim(kirc)[1],]
```